# Handling errors when using custom forms with django-allauth

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth and custom login and signup forms in my application. Everything works well until a user submits an error with the login or signup form.
The error shows up but on a different page.

e.g intended login form is at the URI: [/payment/e886371a-fa52-4718-b8bc-e53fe8ac2bea/](http://#)

However, when there is a form error in the above page, it redirects to the default login URI:  [/accounts/login/](http://#) and displays the error there.

Is there a way to make sure the user is returned to the original page incase of a form error and have the error(s) displayed there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have login form on URI /payment/e886371a-fa52-4718-b8bc-e53fe8ac2bea/ and you do not want to redirect to /account/login, do not write as action of form. And create payment view which can handle authorization directly on payment URI.

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="/payment/e886371a-fa52-4718-b8bc-e53fe8ac2bea/">
...
</form>
```

In your payment view you can extends class allautho/accounts/views/LoginView, which handles normal email/password auth.